# How not to call the second epic if the first one called?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, redux-observable

I have a special epics

```
const extraEpics = combineEpics(someEpic1, someEpicN);
```

Each of which will check their case, and they all listen to the same action

```
action$.pipe(
    ofType(UPDATE_ACTION),
    pluck("payload"),
    filter(checkSomeExtraCase)
```

There is also a default behavior when not one epic does not cause

```
const defaultBehaviorWithoutFilter = action$.pipe(
        ofType(UPDATE_ACTION),
        pluck("payload"),
```

I need to call it when extra logic was filtered
And I try concat

```
export default (action$, state$) =>
  concat(
    extraEpics(action$, state$), 
    defaultBehavior(action$, state$)
  )
```

But when called extra, default will call to
How can I only cause a default when extra has not been called?

Comment: Also, I tried combineLatest, but I need to return Nothing from extra when extra not called instead of the latest value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I think you can take a look at [rxjs-etc](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc) and there is `concatIfEmpty` operator, which is exactly what you want.

```
export default (action$, state$) =>
  extraEpics(action$, state$)
    .pipe(
       concatIfEmpty(defaultBehavior(action$, state$))
     )
```

Comment: But extraEpics can emit more than one action per time

Comment: No race, because defaultBehavior side effects can be faster then extraEpics side effects, but this does not exclude the possibility of extra logic case

Comment: Updated the answer once again - sadly I can't think of a solution without involving custom operator or external lib

Comment: concatIfEmpty :D YES!